# Child > Parent > Child props not appearing on first render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building an app that searches a nutrition api and returns calories etc. As part of it, I am adding a functionality where the user sets their daily calorie amount and macro breakdown (% protein, carbs, fat).

When the user enters their % and clicks calculate, it passes the props from the child (MacroSelector) to the parent (App) and is meant to calculate the grams of protein/fat/carbs needed and pass that down to FoodTable.

However, it does not do it on first click of the calculate button. Instead I need to click "Calculate" twice to pass down the macros to the child. Any help is appreciated.

In MacroSelector, the user inputs what % protein, carbs and fat they want in the inputs. This is then passed up as props to the parent component in macroHandler.

```
const MacroSelector = (props) => {
  const [protein, setProtein] = useState();
  const [carbs, setCarbs] = useState();
  const [fat, setFat] = useState();

  const proteinHandler = (e) => {
    setProtein(e);
  };

  const carbsHandler = (e) => {
    setCarbs(e);
  };

  const fatHandler = (e) => {
    setFat(e);
  };

  const macrosHandler = () => {
    props.macrosHandler({ protein, carbs, fat });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Form
        style={{
          display: "grid",
          gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(24, 1fr)",
        }}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            gridColumn: "1/2",
            lineHeight: "1.8",
            marginLeft: "10px",
            marginRight: "10px",
          }}
        >
          Protein{" "}
        </div>
        <Input
          style={{ gridColumn: "2/4", marginRight: "10px" }}
          type="number"
          name="protein"
          onChange={(e) => proteinHandler(e.target.value)}
        />
        <div
          style={{
            gridColumn: "5/6",
            lineHeight: "1.8",
            marginRight: "10px",
          }}
        >
          Carbs{" "}
        </div>
        <Input
          style={{ gridColumn: "6/8", marginRight: "10px" }}
          type="number"
          name="carbs"
          onChange={(e) => carbsHandler(e.target.value)}
        />
        <div
          style={{
            gridColumn: "9/10",
            lineHeight: "1.8",
            marginRight: "10px",
          }}
        >
          Fat{" "}
        </div>
        <Input
          style={{ gridColumn: "10/12" }}
          type="number"
          name="fat"
          onChange={(e) => fatHandler(e.target.value)}
        />

        <Button
          style={{ gridColumn: "14/18" }}
          name="approve"
          onClick={macrosHandler}
        >
          Calculate
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MacroSelector;
```

In the App component, the function macrosHandler sets the props passed from MacroSelector component as state(setDailyMacroBreakDown). Next we take the calories set by the user, and the % of protein, fat, carbs that they want their diet to be, and work out how many grams of each. We then set this as state with setRemainingMacros.

We then pass remainingMacros as props to the FoodTable component (remainingMacros = {remainingMacros}).
The props are getting passed down but not on the initial click of the "Calculate" button and I am unsure as to why.

If user enters 40 40 20, on first click of calculate, the props passed down are the default state in App for remainingMacros. The second time calculate is clicked, then the props with 40 40 20 are passed down.

Any advice is appreciated!!

```
const App = (props) => {
  const [dailyCalorieSelector, setDailyCalorieSelector] = useState(1800);

  const [foodItemDetails, setFoodItemDetails] = useState([]);

  const [sumOfFoodItems, setSumOfFoodItems] = useState({
    protein: 0,
    carbs: 0,
    calories: 0,
    fat: 0,
  });

  // const [caloriesForMacros, setCaloriesForMacros] = useState();

  const [remainingMacros, setRemainingMacros] = useState({
    protein: 0,
    fat: 0,
    carbs: 0,
  });

  const [dailyMacroBreakdown, setDailyMacroBreakdown] = useState({
    protein: 0,
    carbs: 0,
    fat: 0,
  });

  const removeRow = (props) => {
    let deletedRowNewArray = foodItemDetails.filter((row) => {
      return row.id !== props.id;
    });
    setFoodItemDetails(deletedRowNewArray);

    setSumOfFoodItems({
      fat: sumOfFoodItems.fat - props.fat,
      protein: sumOfFoodItems.protein - props.protein,
      carbs: sumOfFoodItems.carbs - props.carbs,
      calories: sumOfFoodItems.calories - props.calories,
    });
  };

  const macrosHandler = (props) => {
    setDailyMacroBreakdown(props);
    const proteinCalories =
      (dailyCalorieSelector * (dailyMacroBreakdown.protein / 100)) / 4;
    const carbsCalories =
      (dailyCalorieSelector * (dailyMacroBreakdown.carbs / 100)) / 4;
    const fatCalories =
      (dailyCalorieSelector * (dailyMacroBreakdown.fat / 100)) / 9;

    setRemainingMacros({
      protein: proteinCalories,
      carbs: carbsCalories,
      fat: fatCalories,
    });

    console.log("remaining", remainingMacros);
    // setCaloriesForMacros(dailyCalorieSelector);
  };

  const setCalorieHandler = (e) => {
    setDailyCalorieSelector(e.target.value);
  };

  const onSearchSubmit = async (props) => {
    let data = { title: props, ingr: [props] }; //ingr = ingredients list + title required
    await axios
      .post(
        `https://api.edamam.com/api/nutrition-details?app_id=8b84adef&app_key=a931603d6a495dba409096cbf9eb7f71`,
        data
      )
      .then((response) => {
        setFoodItemDetails([
          ...foodItemDetails,
          {
            name: props,
            id: uuidv4(),
            fat: response.data.totalNutrients.FAT.quantity.toFixed(),
            protein: response.data.totalNutrients.PROCNT.quantity.toFixed(),
            carbs: response.data.totalNutrients.CHOCDF.quantity.toFixed(),
            calories: response.data.calories,
          },
        ]);

        setSumOfFoodItems({
          fat:
            sumOfFoodItems.fat +
            parseInt(response.data.totalNutrients.FAT.quantity.toFixed()),
          protein:
            sumOfFoodItems.protein +
            parseInt(response.data.totalNutrients.PROCNT.quantity.toFixed()),
          carbs:
            sumOfFoodItems.carbs +
            parseInt(response.data.totalNutrients.CHOCDF.quantity.toFixed()),
          calories: sumOfFoodItems.calories + response.data.calories,
        });
        // console.log("sumoffood", sumOfFoodItems);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
  return (
    <div className="Card">
      <div
        style={{
          display: "grid",
          gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(12, 1fr)",
          margin: "25px 0px",
        }}
      >
        <div style={{ gridColumn: "3/11" }}>
          <Chart />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <div style={{ width: "50%" }}>
          {dailyMacroBreakdown && (
            <div>
              {" "}
              {`Protein: ${dailyMacroBreakdown.protein}, Carbs: ${dailyMacroBreakdown.carbs}, Fat: ${dailyMacroBreakdown.fat}`}{" "}
            </div>
          )}
        </div>

        <div style={{ width: "50%" }}>
          <Form>
            <Label for="volume">
              {`Select Daily Calorie Intake: ${dailyCalorieSelector}`}
            </Label>

            <Input
              type="range"
              id="volume"
              name="volume"
              min="800"
              max="6000"
              step="10"
              value={dailyCalorieSelector}
              onChange={setCalorieHandler}
            />
          </Form>
        </div>
        <MacroSelector macrosHandler={macrosHandler} />
        <div
          style={{
            display: "grid",
            gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(12, 1fr)",
            margin: "25px 0px",
          }}
        >
          <div style={{ gridColumn: "2/11" }}>
            <Searcher onSearchSubmit={onSearchSubmit} />
          </div>
        </div>

        <FoodTable
          foodItemDetails={foodItemDetails}
          sumOfFoodItems={sumOfFoodItems}
          removeRow={removeRow}
          dailyCalorieSelector={dailyCalorieSelector}
          remainingMacros={remainingMacros}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

The child component that is not receiving the props on first click of calculate is below.

```
const FoodTable = (props) => {
  const { foodItemDetails, sumOfFoodItems } = props;
  const { fat, protein, carbs, calories } = sumOfFoodItems;

  console.log("sumOfFoodItems ", props);

  const removeRow = (e) => {
    props.removeRow(e);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Table striped>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Food & Quantity</th>
            <th>Fat </th>
            <th>Carbs</th>
            <th>Protein</th>
            <th>Calories</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          {foodItemDetails.length > 0 &&
            foodItemDetails.map((foodItem, index) => {
              return (
                <tr key={foodItem.id}>
                  <th scope="row">{index + 1}</th>
                  <td>{foodItem.name}</td>
                  <td>{foodItem.fat} g</td>
                  <td>{foodItem.carbs} g</td>
                  <td>{foodItem.protein} g</td>
                  <td>{foodItem.calories} kCal </td>
                  <td>
                    <BsFillPlusCircleFill
                      onClick={() => removeRow(foodItem)}
                    ></BsFillPlusCircleFill>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
          <tr style={{ backgroundColor: "grey" }}>
            <th scope="row"></th>
            <td style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>Total</td>
            <td>{fat} g</td>
            <td>{carbs} g</td>
            <td>{protein} g</td>
            <td>{calories} kCal </td>
            <td> </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        {props.remainingMacros && (
          <tfoot>
            <tr style={{ backgroundColor: "grey" }}>
              <th scope="row"></th>
              <td style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>Remaining</td>
              <td>{props.remainingMacros.fat - fat} g</td>
              <td>{props.remainingMacros.carbs - carbs} g</td>
              <td>{props.remainingMacros.protein - protein} g</td>
              <td>{props.dailyCalorieSelector - calories} kCal </td>
              <td> </td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
        )}
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
};
export default FoodTable;
```

Comment: It is not clear to me, what your query is. It would be nice if you could rephrase the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies in your `App` component, the `macrosHandler` function. You set the state and immediately perform operations on this state, but you forgot that the setting the state in React is asynchronous. So, instead of this:

```
const macrosHandler = (props) => {
    setDailyMacroBreakdown(props);
    //some operations on dailyMacroBreakdown that doesn't see the changed state
}
```

you could try to listening to the change like this:

```
const macrosHandler = (props) => {
    setDailyMacroBreakdown(props);
}

useEffect(() => {
    //some operations on dailyMacroBreakdown that DO see the updated state
}, [dailyMacroBreakdown]);
```